# How to make duplicate entries in xml with google apps-script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

Im trying to generate an XML file with google apps-script. The XML file should be having 2 link sections like this:

```
<xmeml version="4">
  <sequence>
     <clipitem>
        <link>
           <linkclipref>clipitem-1</linkclipref>
           <mediatype>video</mediatype>
           <trackindex>1</trackindex>
           <clipindex>1</clipindex>
        </link>
        <link>
           <linkclipref>clipitem-2</linkclipref>
           <mediatype>audio</mediatype>
           <trackindex>1</trackindex>
           <clipindex>2</clipindex>
        </link>
     </clipitem>
   </sequence>
</xml>
```

I'm currently using the folowing code:

```
function createXml(e) {
  var xml = new XML('<xmeml/>');
  xml['@version'] = '4';
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.linkclipref = "clipitem-1;
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.mediatype="video";
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.trackindex = 1;
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.clipindex = 1;

  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.linkclipref = "clipitem-2;
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.mediatype="audio";
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.trackindex = 1;
  xml.sequence.clipitem.link.clipindex = 2;
  var xml_result = xml.toString();

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(xml_result, 'text/html', e.parameter.filename + '.xml');
  return blob;
}
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<xmeml version="4">
   <sequence>
      <clipitem>
          <link>
              <linkclipref>clipitem-2</linkclipref>
              <mediatype>audio</mediatype>
              <trackindex>1</trackindex>
              <clipindex>2</clipindex>
          </link>
      </clipitem>
   </sequence>
</xml>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as the second xml.sequence.clipitem overwrites the first one. How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are converting the xml object to string, you can always create xml as string from the beginning.

```
function createXml(e) {
  var data = [["clipitem-1","video",1,1],["clipitem-2","audio",1,2]];
  var xml ='<xmeml version="4"><sequence><clipitem>';
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    xml+="<link><linkclipref>"+data[i][0]+"</linkclipref><mediatype>"+data[i][3]+"</mediatype><mediatype>"+data[i][3]+"</mediatype></link>"
  }
  xml+="</clipitem></sequence></xml>";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(xml, 'text/html', e.parameter.filename + '.xml');
  return blob;
}
```

Comment: While I was hoping for something tidier the idea of breaking it up and pasting the resulting strings back together seems like something that I might use. I'll probably use multiple objects that I convert to string before combining to increase readability.